# What does "D.R." stands for in International Love song by Pitbull?

Tags: lyrics

What does "D.R." stands for in International Love song by Pitbull?
"Down in DR they looking for visa"

> *Down in D.R. they're looking for visas*
>   I ain't talking credit cards if you know what I mean
>   Yeah, en Cuba, la cosa esta dura
>   But the woman get down, if you know what I mean
>   In Colombia the women got everything done
>   But they are some of the most beautiful women I've ever seen
>   In Brazil they're freaky with big old booties
>   And their thongs, blue, yellow and green
>   In L.A. tengo la Mexicana, en New York tengo la boricua
>   Besitos para todas las mujeres en Venezuela, muah
>   Y en Miami tengo a cualquiera

Is it some US immigration office or what? I can't find the information anywhere.

Comment: Look at the title. Now, look at the start of all the other lines in the same stanza: *En Cuba, En Columbia, In Brazil*. Doesn't it look like DR should be the abbreviation of some country?

Comment: BTW... Columbia is not a country, but _Colombia_ is.

Comment: @PeterShor Djibouti? I hardly knew her!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dominican Republic perhaps, given the references to other South/Central American countries in the lyrics, Cuba in particular.   The Dominican Republic shares a border with Haiti, in the same island chain as Cuba.

https://www.google.com/maps/place/Dominican+Republic/@17.2561512,-74.7254173,6z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x8eaf8838def1b6f5:0xa6020f24060df7e0!8m2!3d18.735693!4d-70.162651

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominican_Republic

> The name of the country is often shortened to "the D.R." (la R.D.)"

Comment: Sure...the same way we say D.F. for Mexico City.

Comment: @choster whoops yes, you're right, I'll edit, thanks.